# Recommended Project Structure for Domain Models, Fluent Mappings, Service & Repository

Tags: .net, asp.net, projects-and-solutions

I generally work on web (forms) projects now that contain the following elements:

- Web Application
- Domain Models
- Fluent NHibernate Mappings
- Repositories
- Services

I would like to know if there is a recommended structure for these?
I've seen some solutions that contain:

**Organization.App.Website**

- The website

**Organization.App.Core**

- Mappings
- Models
- Services
- Repositories

  - Extensions
- Helpers

Others that split 'Domain' out into a seperate library of its own etc.

I just wondered if there is a generally recommended approach that I should adopt going forward?